Why does my promotion code generator assign the same code to multiple customers?
I'm working on a plugin for Shopware that generates and assigns promotion codes to customers who leave product reviews. However, I've encountered an issue where two different customers received the same promotion code. Here’s a summary of the functionality and the problem:

Code Generation: In my coupon method, I use uniqid to generate a unique promotion code and send it to the customer via email. Here’s the relevant part of the method:

public function coupon(Request $request, Context $context): Response {
    try {
        $orderEntity = $this->loadOrder($request->request->get('salesChannelId'), $context);
        $this->mailHelper->sendVoucherMail($context, $orderEntity, strtoupper(uniqid('test-')), true);
    } catch (Throwable $t) {
        $this->loggerHelper->logThrowable($t);
    }
    return new Response(null, Response::HTTP_NO_CONTENT);
}



Code Assignment to Order: I have another method updatePromotionCode, which updates the order with the promotion code that was generated:

public function updatePromotionCode(OrderEntity $orderEntity, Context $context, string $promotionCode): bool {
    if ($promotionCode != '') {
        try {
            $customFields = [
                OrderCustomFieldInstaller::CUSTOM_FIELD_PROMOTION_CODE => $promotionCode
            ];
            return $this->updateOrder($orderEntity->getId(), $customFields, $context);
        } catch (\Throwable $e) {
            $this->loggerHelper->logThrowable($e);
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        $this->loggerHelper->addDirectRecord(Logger::WARNING, 'Promotion code not updated in order. Promotion code empty', ["promotionCode" => $promotionCode]);
        return false;
    }
}


Problem:
A customer recently received a promotion code that had already been used by another customer in an order from August. In the database, this code is listed as unused for the new customer but in the shop in promotions, in the list of codes used by customers, it shows the name of the old customer who originally redeemed it. This raises several questions:

Is the plugin actually generating unique codes, or could it be reusing old codes?
If the plugin generates new codes, how could two different customers end up with the same code?
If the plugin is reusing old codes, why would it assign an already used code to a new customer?

My goal is not to make the plugin generate unique codes, but to answer the above questions. If you have any insight on how to answer the above questions, please let me know.

From the documentation: Warning
This function does not guarantee the uniqueness of the return value because the value is based on the current time in microseconds

Use the $more_entropy = true argument to make this less likely.

Barmar gave you the answer, but I'll just add that there have been several attempts at deprecating uniqid, including very recently with PHP 8.4 (which didn't pass). The function's name can sometimes lead to an incorrect assumption of what it does, and it might be worth reading those discussions to see if there is something more appropriate and/or descriptive to use.

Can't you do a while $promotionCode is not unique method?

uniqid is also be very predictable -- as stated before, use more entropy please. Doing a while-code-is-not-unique will just lead to more or less consecutive codes which can easily be predicted.

As stated in the comments you don't use enough entropy.
You might consider using the core functionality to generate codes in Core/Checkout/Promotion/Util/PromotionCodeService.php
